# Split a sting without Duplicates VBA

Tags: vba

Stringtable :

```
Table1.col1 = Table2.Col1
Table1.Col3 = Table3.Col1
Table1.Col4 = Table2.Col6
Table1.Col5 = Table4.Col1
Table1.Col6 = Table3.Col1
```

From the above Stringtable i need just only table names with comma seperated without duplicates
as Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4  as ouput.
i have tried with split function but it didint worked out. can anyone help

Code:

```
  WrdArray() = Split(Stringtable, " = ")
                For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
                   strg = strg & vbNewLine & WrdArray(i)
                Next i
           MsgBox strg
```

Comment: A [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) or [.NET's ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) can help about keeping only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

You've extracted multiple "Table1.col1", "Table2.Col1", etc but need another Split() to cut the "col1", etc from the table names.

Don't output the results in the loop as you haven't removed duplicates yet.  Add them to a list so that you can remove duplicates before iterating the loop and building up your output string

Answer (score 0):

The code could look something like this.
First the `=` will be replaced by `.` so we need to split just once. Then the splited array is looped throught and filtered by case insensitive string `table*`. Finally a `vba-collection` is used to get unique entries. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Public Const equal As String = "="
Public Const dot = "."

Sub GetTableNames()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Set source = Worksheets("source")

    Dim stringTable As Range
    Set stringTable = source.Range("A1:A5")

    stringTable.Replace What:=equal, Replacement:=dot, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Dim checkDuplicity As Collection
    Dim WrdArray As Variant
    Dim stringTableItem As Variant
    Dim part As Variant
    Dim strg As String

    Set checkDuplicity = New Collection

    For Each stringTableItem In stringTable.Value
        WrdArray = Split(stringTableItem, dot)
        For Each part In WrdArray
            part = Trim(part)
            If LCase(part) Like "table*" Then

                On Error Resume Next

                checkDuplicity.Add part, part
                If Err.Number = 0 Then _
                    strg = strg & vbNewLine & part

                On Error GoTo 0

            End If

        Next part
    Next stringTableItem

    MsgBox strg

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dee. appricaite your help , table* ( Its just an example i quoted . table name varies .i can be xyz or customertable. Any modidactions  in ur code may help me

Comment: If ```table*``` was just an example then edit your question and add all possible texts you want to filter out. Because I can't modify the code when I don't know what is expected.